# How to store related data

Tags: c#, list

In my program (a program that assists with pathfinding), i need to store a list that contains entries consisting of a start node and an end node. A dictionary won't work as i cannot guarantee that the "key" (a node of course) will be unique. What is the best way to store this manner of data?
Edit: i use C# and .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be better off simply using an array of structs. Or a vector of structs. This allows for non-unique nodes in your list. Vectors are a standard template in C++, but if C# doesn't support it, then an array should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible for you to use a List of KeyValuePair objects? Like this?

```
List<KeyValuePair<ObjectA, ObjectB>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<ObjectA, ObjectB>>();
```

I don't have VS in front of me right now, so I'm not sure if I have the syntax 100% right, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: That might work, but what happens when i want to store 3 or more sets of related items?

Comment: In that instance you would have to look at implementing a new object to provide to List<T>.

Answer (score 0):

If your language of choice supports sets, a set of (start, end) tuples is what you might be looking for.

Comment: You could also emulate a set by using a dictionary with the (s.e) edges as keys.  You can either ignore the values or use them for storing some useful info about the respective edges of your graph.

Comment: Darn, .net doesnt really support tuples or sets. Thanks for the idea though!